# Setting up a Mac Mountain Lion NFS client to securely access Debian NFS server

Tags: debian, mac-osx, nfs, kerberos

Okay, I’m going just about insane here.

Trying to set up an OS X (10.8.2) NFS client to connect to Debian (6.0.6) nfs server. I’ve mostly been following instructions here: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NFSv4Howto which are very thorough. However, two issues:

- When I *don’t* use Kerberos, the performance sucks (I think something must be timing-out), and all the files are apparently owned by nobody:nobody. Doing an `ls` of the mounted directory takes tens of seconds.
- When I *do* try to use Kerberos, with a principal created for the server and for the client, I cannot mount the share. The client complains: `mount_nfs: can't mount /mnt from servername.domain onto /home: Permission denied`

I’ve set up two principals, `nfs/servername@REALM` and `nfs/clientname@REALM`, and copied into `/etc/krb5.keytab` on client and server.

The server is (according to Kerberos logs) getting tickets for `nfs/servername.REALM` so my suspicion is that the OS X NFS client isn't using its principal somehow.

Any ideas?

**Update:** `/var/log/daemon.log` reports:

```
Oct  7 19:12:43 servername rpc.svcgssd[19635]: ERROR: GSS-API: error in handle_nullreq: gss_accept_sec_context(): Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information - No supported encryption types (config file error?)
```

As per this page: http://permalink.gmane.org/gmane.comp.encryption.kerberos.heimdal.general/5551 I’ve removed all but the DES encryption options in both client and server krb5.keytab files. And added `allow_weak_crypto` in the `/etc/krb5.conf` file. And restarted `hfs-kernel-server` and it still doesn’t work. Sigh.

Actually, now it reports:

```
Oct  7 19:26:55 servername rpc.svcgssd[19721]: ERROR: GSS-API: error in handle_nullreq: gss_accept_sec_context(): Unspecified GSS failure.  Minor code may provide more information - Wrong principal in request
```

Does that “Wrong principal in request” mean that the client is passing the wrong krb5 principal? Can I control that in OS X?

Answer (score 3):

NFSv4 seems to be fairly broken under Mac OS X 10.8.
The unofficial word is that Apple is aware of the issue but doesn't have a timeline for fixing it. Meanwhile, the consensus is that opendirectoryd is quite broken.

A few places that you might check for better debugging info:

1. `# sysctl -w vfs.generic.nfs.client.idmap_ctrl=127`
   Watch the output of `/var/log/system.log` while your are trying to run the `ls` command.
2. `# odutil set log debug`
   Watch the output of `/var/log/opendirectoryd.log`
3. Use `dtrace` to figure out where the hangup is.
   Our experience has been that `nfs4_id2guid` is timing out because opendirectoryd isn't always registering itself properly with the kernel.

Answer (score 0):

I thing you should try to create two others principals with your domain name added to your server name.

Like `nfs/mysername.example.com@REALM` and `host/myclientname.example.com@REALM`

But anyway, on MacOSX You have to have a TGT BEFORE trying to mount.

So before the mount try a kinit (any principal is ok).

Personnaly, I manage to have an nfs+kerberos on MacOSX. But in NFSV3.

In NFSV4 I manage to mount it, but it's slow... very slow.

Comment: These details are difficult to follow. Can you add some more specific info as to how you were able to setup the NFS client on MacOSX?

Comment: What are you trying to do ? Because create an NFS client on Mac OSX is a very simple job : go -> connect... -> nfs://servername/. But if you want create the server + client + kerberos ... this is another job.